# Keep a radio button checked after submit

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to keep a radio button checked even after submission (in Angular).

```
<label class="container" *ngFor="let content of contents; let idx = index">
    <input type="radio"
       value={{content}}
       (change)="radioChangeHandler($event)"  name="radio">
       {{content}}
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: you need to decide if you write Contenu or contenu.

Comment: I wrote a quick [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-form-eazaym) that retains the value after submission.

Comment: thank you michael this work for me

Answer (score 0):

You could make a var to hold the selected value and with the checked attribute keep it checked if the selected value is the same as the button's content.

```
selectedValue: any;

<label class="container" *ngFor="let content of contents; let idx = index">
  <input type="radio"
  value={{content}}
  [checked]="content === selectedValue"
  (change)="radioChangeHandler($event)"  name="radio">
  {{content}}
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

radioChangeHandler(event: any) {
  this.selectedValue = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: radioChangeHandler(event: any) {
  this.selectedValue = event.target.value
}

Answer (score 0):

When front-end sends data (object, array, etc) to the back-end, it receives response. This response may contain various types of information, including data showing what it is received by the back-end. Use the response for mapping (and keeping the stored data still visible on your form).